# PHP - PDO Library Return Results

Tags: php, foreach, pdo

I'm trying to return a single result out of my database using the PDO library, but the only way to return what I want is to put it into a foreach loop.

Here is how I'm querying my database and fetching the data.

```
<?  $query = " 
    SELECT 
        theme 
    FROM ncms_settings 
";      
try 
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{  
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); ?>
```

How do I return the data by just doing

```
echo $rows['theme'];
```

instead of

```
<? foreach($rows as $row): ?>
   $echo $row['theme']
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Assuming you have 42 rows returned, what value would you expect for `$rows['theme']` (if it worked)?

Comment: I only have one row, it should return 1.

Comment: Why am I getting voted down? I provided all possible information and what I've tried, is it because the answer is obvious to most? I'm sorry if it is I'm learning. **Edit** Thank you for the up vote, who ever it was =]

Comment: You were voted down because _you didn't make your homework_ as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Your question can be resolved by just rading the PDO's documentation, more specifically here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 2):

If it's only a single row returned - just use

```
$stmt->fetch() // returns a single row (array of fields)
```

instead of

```
$stmt->fetchAll() // returns all rows (array of arrays of fields)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Perfect! New to the PDO library, kinda figured fetchAll was all I needed, thank you very much.